# How to solve TypeError exception with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to check my data and see images containing in `images.npy`. How to solve that type of error?

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (20000, 48, 48, 3) for image data
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

images = np.load('images.npy')

plt.imshow(images)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your data is 4-dimensional.  imshow requires 2- or 3-dimensional data. https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: Where oh where did the error occur.  Don't just show code and an error summary!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot plot a 4d array that way. Try to split the first dimension 20000 into individual RGB images and then plot them using `plt.subplots` instead.

Comment: As I understand the"20000" is the number of images in file. But thank you I'll try

Comment: Yes, you can treat that 4d array as a list of 20000 RGB images, and plot them separately use their indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try: (from https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/images.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('images.npy')

imgplot = plt.imshow(img[0])#plot the first -- notice you are trying to plot 20k images, not 1
```